# Number of submatrix with sum k

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I just came around this question in a programming contest and was unable to solve it within required time constraints.So just curious to get the right approach.Any suggestions would be helpful.

Input
Given a matix a[] with n elements where n<1000.
an integer k where k<10^9

Construct a new matrix b where `b[i][j]=a[i]*a[j]`.

Output
Number of possible submatrix with sum k.

Test case

```
a[]={1,-1}
k=0
```

output=5
explaination

```
b={ 1,-1,
   -1, 1}
```

so 2 row subsets,2 column subsets and 1 complete array. so total 5.

I tried to solve using something like this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639172/submatrix-with-sum-k

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a programming contest question dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a sub array sum `b[i][j] -> b[i + m]b[j + n]`, it is equals to

```
X =   a[i]*(a[j] + a[j + 1] + ... + a[j + n])
    + a[i + 1]*(a[j] + a[j + 1] + ... + a[j + n])
    + ...
    + a[i + m]*(a[j] + a[j + 1] + ... + a[j + n])
  = sum(a[i] + ..a[i + m])*sum(a[j] +... a[j + n])
```

So, the task is reduced to find two segments in array `a`, and their sums multiply together equals to `k`.

To find all segments sum in `a`, it can be done in **O(n^2)**.

Store all of the sum in a `HashSet`, or similar, and we can find the answer in **O(n^2)** time complexity.

Comment: done..I think we can reduce the complexity of the second step too(finding sum of all segments.)

Comment: @MuditAgarwal yes, we only need to check for all numbers `a` which, `k % a == 0` and `a <= square_root(k)`, so the checking step is `O(square_root(k))` Remember to take care of positive and negative cases.